# Why Create a Generator Manually for Neural Network when Keras has Built-in Generators?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

So many tutorials I see have manually created generators in order to use the fit_generator() command in the model-fitting stage. However, these seem to exist already in Keras. E.g.,

```
keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator()
```

Is this not correct? E.g. can I do,

```
train_gen = keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(someParameters)
model.fit_generator(train_gen, someOtherParameters)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If something pre-packaged doesn't suit your needs, then you'll have to write something new. It seems like you've found something pre-packaged that solves one problem. But I see no indication that this pre-packaged function solves all possible problems.